# Sound is not going to stop on click event in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, html, audio, aframe

```
 <a-assets>
          <audio id="river" src="river.mp3" preload="auto">
          </audio>   
 </a-assets>   
 <a-entity sound="src: #river"></a-entity>
```

```
var entity = document.querySelector('[sound]');
entity.components.sound.stopSound();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. In this case what is the question?

Comment: i guess the question is: why doesn't it work. To be honest, trying to duplicate this code, my .mp3 does not stop either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `document.querySelector('audio').stop();` work or `entity.pause()`?

Comment: I have tried document.querySelector('audio').stop(); work or entity.pause() but not working. getting error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of null